# Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin - yet page is actually secure

Tags: security, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a website fully secured with CloudFlare SSL/TLS. Am trying to upgrade some page to a "Progressive Web Application"... Everything required by the [Progressive Web Application Checklist](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) is in place. I can even see the "**Add to homescreen**" link in the **Manifest** option of **Application** tab in Debug Tools - but alas when I click add to homescreen Google Chrome doesn't allow my page to install neither show an app banner. Under **Console** tab I see the error "Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin"... It's the only error I note. Yet in the **Security** tab Chrome reports that **This page is secure (valid HTTPS).**

What could be wrong? How can I proceed with the work?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "My PWA",
  "name": "My PWA - Live Marketplace Status Updates",
  "icons": [{
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x256.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x768.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "768x768"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/s3-icon-x1024.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "1024x1024"
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#f7c723",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/home?launcher=true"
}
```

Comment: show your manifest.json

Comment: try lookiing at serviceworker debugging -  ./chrome  --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://your.insecure.site

Comment: Having exact same problem. I've just reported the issue here -- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=793626